# Connecting to a local MySQL Server through Dreamweaver?

Tags: php, mysql, dreamweaver

On MySQL Workbench I have a Connection (properly running) with a Database I want to access through dreamweaver when pressing F12.I have a PHP script that accesses the database.

My issue is that when pressing F12 on Dreamweaver on my script, after updating the cache I get directed to:

> Not Found HTTP Error 404

[image]

I configured my site wrong above but don't know what to input for the parameters.

---

edit: On my PHP Script I have:

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_NAME', 'user_collection');
define('DB_USER','jonab12');
define('DB_PASSWORD','jonab12');

$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error());
```

Does this conflict with the testing server? I would doubt it since a testing server is mandatory in itself.

Comment: Try making the endpoint the PHP script itself, instead of the root page of your host?